# Why is there no negative mass?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, charge, coulombs-law, exotic-matter

We know that the entire matter has a property called mass. Charge is also a property of matter. If negative charge can exist, why don't negative mass exist?

Also, like charges repel each other. Then why like masses attract each other?

Comment: Hi. Are we sure that charge is a property of matter?

Comment: If you are asking with reference to topic of negative energy in wikipedia, know that "that" energy is commonly called as potential energy.What you are asking is equivalent of asking why dont negative "mass" energies exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does matter with negative mass exist?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44934/)

Comment: Other possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18925/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34115/2451 and links therein.