# What is the time-dilation at the surface of an antineutron star? (Does antimatter generate gravitons, an extension of the SM, as matter does?)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, time-dilation, antimatter, neutron-stars

The time-dilation at the surface of a [matter] neutron star is calculated to approximately be four times slower than flat space-time, conventional quantum mechanics treats antiparticles as traveling backwards in time, but we may never observe an antineutron star because of baryon asymmetry, stable antinuclei have been produced at several facilities so stable anti-neutronium is definitely possible, the real core question about antimatter is how it affects ***time***.

Addendum: to be clear, I'm asking for an explanation/answer that jives with conventional understanding such as: gravitons are a conventional extension of the SM, matter and antimatter are considered different kinds of mass **NOT** "antimass", ergo, time-dilation near an antineutron star should be *exactly the same* as time-dilation near a neutron star - **with the explicit understanding that we consider antimatter generating gravitons exactly the same as matter**, that's the kind of answer i'm looking for.

Comment: I think you are mixing up [antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter) and [exotic matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter). Antimatter is just another form of matter and has the same gravitational field as matter. So the time dilation at the surface of an antineutron star would be the same as at the surface of a neutron star.

Comment: Hi Salvatore. Your answer has been closed by a moderator on the grounds it isn't clear what you are asking about. Part of the problem is that antimatter is **not** matter moving backwards in time. If you can edit your question to clarify that you are asking whether antimatter affects time dilation in the same way that matter does the question could be reopened.

Comment: Although I think your question is covered by two previous questions [Has the gravitational interaction of antimatter ever been examined experimentally?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139545/has-the-gravitational-interaction-of-antimatter-ever-been-examined-experimentall) and [Gravity, matter vs antimatter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534289/gravity-matter-vs-antimatter).

Comment: Neutron stars are not made of "neutronium".