# Is anti-matter less dense than a vacuum?

Tags: mass, vacuum, density, antimatter, buoyancy

Fill a balloon with Helium and it floats (it is buoyant in air). 'Fill' a balloon with a vacuum (not withstanding the difficulty of a structurally stable void) and it is more buoyant as it is less dense. If you filled a balloon with a theoretical 'anti-helium' (not withstanding annihilation) - would it be more or less dense than the vacuum. Would it 'float' as per posi-helium, sink or would it be twice as buoyant, relatively.

Comment: Why would the anti-helium behave any different than the helium in this context? If the implication here is supposed to be that anti-matter also produces anti-gravity, then see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83307/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534289/50583 and their linked questions

Answer (score 4):

Antimatter is experimentally known to have positive energy density and positive inertial mass. Antimatter responds to electromagnetic fields exactly as we would expect a particle of their mass and charge to respond.

We expect that antimatter also responds to gravity exactly as we would expect a particle of their mass to respond. In other words, we expect antimatter to fall down, not up and we expect a large clump of antimatter to gravitationally attract both matter and other antimatter. However, to date that has not been experimentally confirmed due to the weakness of gravity.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AEgIS_experiment

Answer (score 3):

The question is based on a false premise: that the buoyant force on an object depends on the density of the object

In fact, the buoyant force on an object depends only on the **volume** of the **object**, the **density** of the **medium**, and the local **acceleration of gravity**.  A cubic metre container submerged in water experiences a buoyant force of  $9,800$ Newtons, irrespective of whether it is filled with vacuum, hydrogen, helium, air, iron, lead, or osmium (densest element, $22.9$ g/cc).

The density of the submerged object only becomes important if one wishes to know the **net** result of the combined forces of gravity and buoyancy on the object. The answer of @Dale deals with this question in regard to antimatter.