# The mass of a photon

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, quantum-electrodynamics

When particles increase their speeds, their (relativistic) mass increases. But this isn't observed in the case of a photon. So it was deducted that the rest mass of a photon is zero. Why is the rest mass of a photon zero?

Comment: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-apparently-elementary-particles/the-known-particles-if-the-higgs-field-were-zero/

Comment: Your statement applies to particles that HAVE rest mass, but light has no rest mass, it is a fundamental known property of light.( It's the same as asking why does an electron have charge- no one really knows exactly why).

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31994/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191451/2451 and links therein.