# Masslessness of the electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

> Why is the electromagnetic field massless?

I presume the mass term in the Lagrangian,
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}M^2 A_{\mu}A^{\mu},
$$

would "violate" gauge redundancy.

But this is what its name indicates: redundancy!

Who cares if it's lost? What are the consequences of losing gauge redundancy in order of importance?

p.s.: On a more serious note: how does one improve his questions?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31994/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191451/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Can you rephrase the p.s.? I don't know what you meant.

Comment: You can perfectly have massive vector particles, they will not have gauge invariance though. The statement is that you need gauge invariance to describe massless vector particles.

Comment: As @PeterKravchuk points out in their comment and in more detail in their answer, you would have a perfectly legitimate theory if you include the mass-term. However, it would be a different theory and not an appropriate model to describe QED because, as we know, QED photon is massless. The point is that in order to ensure the massless photon, you need to impose gauge symmetry--if you chuck out the mass-term by hand without imposing the gauge symmetry, your theory would be non-renormalizable or would need fine-tuning, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have massive vector fields. These fields will not have gauge-invariance. This is not a problem, we didn't ask for gauge invariance when constructing the theory of electromagnetism. The problem is that massive fields mediate interactions that fall off as $r^\# e^{-mr}$, where $m$ is the mass of the field, and $r$ is the distance. Because of the exponential fall-off, the range of the force will be $1/m$.

For massless photons the force falls off as $1/r^2$, making it long range.

Since we know static electromagnetism has rather long range (EM waves are not relevant here -- these correspond to real photons, while force is being mediated by virtual photons), we are pretty sure that photon is massless. Furthermore, if photon was massive, the speed of light would depend on the reference system. You can find some discussion and links regarding bounds on photon mass on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Experimental_checks_on_photon_mass). [Particle data group](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/DataBlock.action?node=S000M) gives a list of upper bounds on photon mass, with their accepted upper bound being $10^{-18}$ eV. (The bound quoted on wikipedia page is debated.) This corresponds to range of force of at least $10^{11}$ meters. This is the same order of magnitude as distance to the Sun.

Answer (score 1):

Gauge symmetry is a redundancy in the sense that it stems from the fact that we describe an object with more degrees of freedom than those that are actually needed. That is $A_\mu$ and $A_\mu + \partial_\mu \phi$ describe the same physical object, and thus any total derivative contribution to $A_\mu$ is redundant.

Now the conclusion that must be drawn from this fact is precisely the opposite. Since gauge symmetry is a redundancy than it is sacred! If it's broken, i.e.  $A_\mu$ and $A_\mu + \partial_\mu \phi$ give different physical consequences, it means that the *same* physical object behaves differently if we describe it differently on paper. This is of course absurd.

Moreover, $A_\mu$ is never measured, but $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ is. So after measuring a certain value of $F$ it better be that, no matter the choice we make for writing down an $A$, the result is the same.

Comment: In principle the statement of gauge invariance is testable. In practice this is very close to impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Testing gauge invariance in what sense?

Comment: Electromagnetic fields have energy momentum. Gauge invariant theory claims a specific, GI, expression for energy momentum. As this the source of gravitation, the correctness of this expression can in principle be tested. In practice this seems impossible as the effect is very small.