# Can a particle have a speed exceeding that of a photon in vacuum?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, faster-than-light, tachyon

Actually I have studied that the smaller the mass of a particle, the fastest it can travel in space. (But i don't know the mass of a single proton) and my question is: can any particle travel faster than a single photon?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11320/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Not in a vacuum - but certainly in a material.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tachyons and Photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11320/)